# Criteria is plural, of course, but

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I know that criteria is plural, but I am trying to explain a situation in which possibly the set of criterion should be considered singular.

In this situation, the set of criterion, called Criteria B, is necessary for a specific determination to be made. The sentence in questions says, "If Criteria B is negative, evaluators do not need to complete a comprehensive Criteria C."

or should it be:

"If Criteria B are negative, evaluators do not need to complete comprehensive Criteria C"

I do not see this particular scenario addressed in other discussions of criteria/criterion.

Comment: The wording itself is quite odd. What is a ‘set of criterion’ (_criterion_ being singular—sets usually comprise plural things, so here we would expect _set of criteria_)? Moreover, this isn't really about the word _criterion/-a_ at all. Your question would be the same if you called the sets _Tests A_ and _Tests B_. And “If Tests A is/are negative…” would still sound odd. Sets are not normally negative or positive.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article at [grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/criteria-criterion/), **criteria** is gaining traction as a singular noun, and appears in that role in notable publications.

> Although criterion lives, criteria is gaining ground as a singular
>   noun, as used below:
>
> Careful though… this criteria is a double edged sword. [Schriever Air
>   Force Base]
>
> The only criteria is that it must be partially or completely open to
>   the public. [Houston Business Journal]
>
> Dark matter is another criteria that is examined. [Universe Today]

Based on this, I'd not deem *`If Criteria B is negative...`* to be incorrect.

Purists would prefer *`If Criteria B are negative...`*, though, in my opinion. The [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/criterion?q=criteria) still considers the singular usage a 'common mistake'.

> Strictly speaking, the singular form (following the original Greek) is
>   criterion and the plural form is criteria. It is a common mistake to
>   use criteria as if it were a singular, as in a further criteria needs
>   to be considered.

Which one you should use depends largely on the audience. I'd say go with the singular, which is more widely used and isn't outright wrong; unless you have reason to believe your audience is likely to frown upon the controversial usage of the singular. It's like deciding whether you'll end a sentence with a preposition or not.

Comment: It may be "gaining traction" but I wouldn't use it in a paper or other formal setting.

Comment: Like many "common mistakes", one shouldn't mistake comonness for correctness. Most people were not taught "criterion", so they don't know how and when to use it.  But I don't think that's what the questioner is asking.

Comment: One problem is that one does not _complete_ criteria. One completes tests or evaluations _using criteria_.

Comment: Also, you don't say the criteria were "negative", you say that X _failed to meet_ the set of citeria (B), and so does not need _to be tested against_ the other set of criteria (C).